# Is every subgroup of a finite abelian $p$-group $G$ arisen from some decomposition of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

Is every subgroup of a finite abelian $p$-group $G$ arisen from some decomposition of $G$?

To be specific, given a finite abelian $p$-group $G$ and pick any subgroup $H \leq G$. Is there always some decomposition of $G$ into direct sum of cyclic groups $G=\oplus_{k=1}^n C_k$, so that $H$ can be written as $H=\oplus_{k=1}^n D_k$ with $D_k \leq C_k$? Notice that I ask about "=" rather than "isomorphic to".

Can anyone please help?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry for the abuse of terms. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Can you explain what the decomposition would be for $\langle 2\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr That is not a counterexample. But the answer to the question is no. I can see the same question on the list of related posts on the right of my screen.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Assume the symbol in my question, let $G=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, $H = \langle 2 \rangle$, then the decomposition of $G$ is just$G = C_1$ where $C_1 = \langle 1 \rangle $, and we can write $H = D_1$ with $D_1 = \langle 1 \rangle \leq C_1 $.

Comment: @DerekHolt Would you mind giving me a counterexample? I think the failure of my own attempt to construct one is due to the lack of knowledge about abelian $p$-groups of higher order, but I am not sure.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851038)

Comment: @DerekHolt That is quite clear. Thank you for your help. It happens unfortunatly that my familiarity about the precise structure of groups is only up to order $15$. So it took me quite a lot of efforts to search for a counterexample.